# Mongo's Cursor.nextObject Sometimes Erroneously Returns Null?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm combining `async.queue` and `Cursor.nextObject` to iterate over a cursor and do some asynchronous work against the returned documents.

There's a great little package that already does this, https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongo-cursor-processing, but it unfortunately doesn't expose the underlying queue, which I need.

So, I tried implementing it myself, but have hit a snag.  Sometimes, `Cursor.nextObject` returns `null` when in fact there are more documents.

Here's a little code snippet that I've attached to the queue to illustrate:

```
if (this.cursor && this.length() < this.concurrency) {
    this.cursor.nextObject(function(err, item) {
        console.log(this.name + ': ' + (item ? item._id : '<null>') + ' ' + (err ? err : '<null>'));
        if (item) {
            this.push(item);
        } else {
            // delete this.cursor;
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

The console log shows:

```
... Maybe 100 lines ...
prop-queue: 511abbd59c0d972a3e000119 <none>
prop-queue: 511abbd59c0d972a3e00011d <none>
prop-queue: 511abbd59c0d972a3e000120 <none>
prop-queue: 511abbd59c0d972a3e000122 <none>
prop-queue: <none> <none>
prop-queue: 511abbd59c0d972a3e000125 <none>
prop-queue: 511abbd59c0d972a3e000127 <none>
prop-queue: 511abbd59c0d972a3e000129 <none>
prop-queue: 511abbd59c0d972a3e00012c <none>
... 1000's more lines before the next null ...
```

Sometimes, the `<none> <none>` line is repeated twice before the next call succeeds.

The really interesting part is when I execute the query in the Mongo shell, there's a pause in between when `511abbd59c0d972a3e000122` and `511abbd59c0d972a3e000125` are printed to console.  The pause lasts about 0.75s, and is right where the null document is hit in the cursor.  I've iterated over thousands of documents in the query, and it's the only pause I experienced.  Furthermore, examining the two documents on either side of the null shows no peculiarities.

Any ideas what could cause the two likely-related phenomena?

Comment: You would be better off using the [event stream interface] than calling `.nextObject()`. You can add items to the "queue" basically on the "data" event for node streams. The node driver for MongoDB supports returning a cursor as a stream, and in fact methods like `aggregate()` simply return what is basically already a readable stream.

Comment: @NeilLunn Are you talking about http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#stream ?  If so, how would I "slow down" the stream if I'm busy processing already-received documents?  The impetus behind the whole queue idea is that I was using `each()` before, but my process kept running out of memory and getting OOM-killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what's causing the pause, but it seems that is the culprit.

During the pause, `Cursor.nextObject` is getting called several times before the first returns.  Some of these calls are returning `null`.  The solution is to make sure `Cursor.nextObject` is never called concurrently.

```
if (this.cursor && !this.cursor_exec && this.length() < this.concurrency) {
    this.cursor_exec = true;
    this.cursor.nextObject(function(err, item) {
        console.log(this.name + ': ' + (item ? item._id : null) + ' ' + (err ? err : null));
        this.cursor_exec = false;
        if (item) {
            this.push(item);
        } else {
            delete this.cursor;
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```