# Calling `cursor.next()` multiple times concurrently crashes the driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

## Motivation:

I have an architecture that involves many workers that "consume" docs like this:

```
worker.on('readyForAnotherDoc', () => worker.consume( await cursor.next() ));
```

That's sort of pseudo-code - I am checking `cursor.hasNext()` in the real code. There are hundreds of workers so `cursor.next()` could get hit by a sudden burst of 200 requests at once.

I'm trying to work around a bug/quirk in the mongodb node.js driver that results in errors if too many of my requests to `cursor.next()` "overlap" with one another by coincidence.

## Background:

It seems like the MongoDB Node.js driver doesn't properly handle the case where `cursor.next` has a burst of requests thrown at it. Try running this code:

```
(async function() {

  // create a collection for testing:
  let db = await require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tester-db-478364');
  await db.collection("test").drop();
  for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    await db.collection("test").insertOne({num:i, foo:'bar'});
  }

  let cursor = await db.collection("test").find({});

  async function go() {
    let doc = await cursor.next();
    console.log(doc.num);
  }

  // start 100 simulataneous requests to `cursor.next()`
  for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    go();
  }

})();
```

This is what it outputs for me:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
/home/joe/Downloads/testtt/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:410
    if(workItem.socketTimeout) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'socketTimeout' of null
    at Connection.messageHandler (/home/me/Downloads/testtt/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:410:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/me/Downloads/testtt/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:361:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:239:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:197:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:589:20)
```

So it looks like it goes fine until the current batch is exhausted. But it's strange because if you add `.batchSize(100)` after `.find({})`, then it doesn't fix it. But interestingly if you add `.batchSize(5)`, you get this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
/home/joe/Downloads/testtt/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:410
    if(workItem.socketTimeout) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'socketTimeout' of null
etc...
```

Not sure what's going on there...

## Trying to work around it:

But let's say we're just after a workaround at this point. Let's say we change our `go` function a bit:

```
let cursorBusy = false;
async function go() {
  if(cursorBusy) await waitForCursor();
  cursorBusy = true;
  let doc = await cursor.next();
  cursorBusy = false;
  console.log(doc.num);
}
function waitForCursor() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let si = setInterval(() => {
      if(!cursorBusy) {
        resolve();
        clearInterval(si);
      }
    }, 50);
  });
}
```

This results in a new error which seems to come up in amongst the `console.log(doc.num)`s here and there:

```
...
359
415
466
(node:16259) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 12): MongoError: clientcursor already in use? driver problem?
427
433
459
...
```

I think that doesn't avoid the bug because of a sort of "race condition" thing with the setInterval. Interesting that it's a different error message though.

**Question:** Is there any way to test if the cursor is currently "busy"? Any other potential workarounds here until this bug is fixed (if it is even a bug)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155180/mongos-cursor-nextobject-sometimes-erroneously-returns-null) has some similar (but definitely not the same) behaviour, and [similar issues](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-core/issues/199) seem to have come up in third-party node.js libs.

Comment: Umm. Can't reproduce. First listing should work exactly as expected, since you do actually `await` the `.next()` "within" the function. So there is nothing "concurrent" about it. You don't actually `await` the `cursor`, where you return from `.find(). It's not async at that point until you "fetch something". So I can give you a corrected listing, but you actually just made a mistake in the coding.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why aren't you using `await go();`? Your current code is synchronously calling `cursor.next()` in a loop which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "multiple independent parts of my code-base that need to read from the same cursor" sounds like a suspect approach.

Comment: @NeilLunn Strange you can't reproduce this. Did you run that exact snippet? Maybe try upping the for-loop count to 1000 or something? Perhaps your computer is too powerful to produce the error with the above code. The `await cursor ...` is *inside* the go function, which is called many times "concurrently".

Comment: @JoeRocc You are really missing that just because you do not `await go()` does not mean those are "concurrent". Each iteration still "awaits" the resolution of `.next()` in the function internals before continuing, so it does not matter where it is. What matters is the understanding of what happens. Which is what I explain in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, by "concurrent" I meant that there are many requests to the cursor "pending" at the same time. [Here's a simple example](http://jsbin.com/cunobuyone/edit?js,console) of what I mean. The promises are all waiting together, at once, rather than serially. But it looks like the problem isn't to do with this (I've replied to your answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your listing. So really just cleaning it up a little:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

(async function() {

  let db;

  try {
    db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    await db.collection('test').drop();

    await db.collection('test').insertMany(
      Array(1000).fill(1).map((e,num) => ({ num, foo: 'bar' }))
    );

    // This is not async. It returns immediately
    let cursor = db.collection('test').find();

    async function go() {
      let doc = await cursor.next();   // This awaits before continuing. Not concurrent.
      console.log(doc.num);
    }

    for ( let i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
      go();  // Note that these "await" internally
    }

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }

})();
```

To **really bulletproof** it, then you really should `await` each operation. So adding in a `Promise.resolve()` on return and `await go()` for good measure, as well as forcing breaking conditions by reducing the batch size:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

(async function() {

  let db;

  try {
    db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    await db.collection('test').drop();

    await db.collection('test').insertMany(
      Array(1000).fill(1).map((e,num) => ({ num, foo: 'bar' }))
    );

    let cursor = db.collection('test').find().batchSize(1);

    async function go() {
      let doc = await cursor.next();
      console.log(doc.num);
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    for ( let i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
      await go();
    }

    console.log('done');


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }


})();
```

Correctly prints out in sequence. Shortened, but actually goes to `99` as expected:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
(etc..)
```

The explanation is mostly in the comments on the code and you seem to be missing which things are `async` and which things are **not**.

So returning a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html) as from [`.find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find) is **not** an `async` method, and returns immediately. This is because it's just a handle to an operation and does not do anything at this point. The MongoDB driver ( all of them ) does not contact the server or establish the cursor at that end until an actual request to "fetch" data is made.

When you call [`.next()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#next) is when there is actual communication to the server and a "batch" of results is returned. The "batch" really only affects whether on not subsequent calls actually go back to the server or not to retrieve data, being that the "batch" may already have "more" results that can be "emptied" before another request for a "batch" is made. At any rate, each call to [`.next()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#next) **is** considered `async`, whether there is external I/O or not.

Typically you call with [`.hasNext()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#hasNext) wrapping each iteration ( which is also `async` ) because calling [`.next()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#next) on a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html) with no more results is an error. It's also generally a means of "loop control" as in the following:

```
(async function() {

  let db;

  try {
    db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    await db.collection('test').drop();

    await db.collection('test').insertMany(
      Array(1000).fill(1).map((e,num) => ({ num, foo: 'bar' }))
    );

    let cursor = db.collection('test').find();

    async function go() {
      let doc = await cursor.next();
      console.log(doc.num);
    }

    //for ( let i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    while( await cursor.hasNext() ) {  // Check the cursor still has results
      go();
    }

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }

})();
```

Which then varies to loop until the end of cursor.

The thing to note about "concurrency" is also it's not generally what you are expecting here. If you did indeed want to make multiple requests in parallel then you still need to wait for a current cursor fetch. If you do not do that then you are asking the server to return the **same** data on all requests, rather than the **sequential** data in "iterating" a cursor.

What you seem to be confusing this with is what some utility functions ( notably mongoose `asyncEach()` does in implementing parallel "fetch". Where the code ( from memory ) is basically artificially inserting a `setTimeout()`in order to await the **"next tick"**, which basically means each `.next()` must actually fire still.

As noted, it's "artificial" in that the batches just effectively `.map()` ( somewhere in underlying code ) into one larger batch.

But as demonstrated. The basic intended usage does actually work as expected due to actually "awaiting" each `.next()`. Just like you should.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think there may have been some miscommunication/misunderstanding regarding what I meant by "concurrent". And thanks for the tip on not `await`ing `cursor.find`. But in any case, this is strange. When I remove the `finally` black from your code, it reproduces my error. Why does it crash without that block?

Comment: @JoeRocc What you are mainly seeing is because of uncaught exceptions. I actually thought a little more on this over lunch and added a second revision on the listing that will ensure it's all in sequence. The part you really need to be understanding is "where the I/O request is inititiated", which I already explain. This is why you do not want to call `.next()` in a loop without `.hasNext()` wrapping that call. Otherwise multiple calls actually try to instantiate the cursor on the server. Note where I am reducing `.batchSize()` to force the issue as well.

Comment: Yeah, I think the first code block (and the last one) could cause the database connection to be closed prematurely. For example, if you add `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));` as the first line in the `go` function, then you get `MongoError: Topology was destroyed`. Are you sure that `.hasNext` is needed? If I add `if(!await cursor.hasNext()) return;` to the go function before the `cursor.next()` line, I still get the error (so long as I don't have that `finally` block).

Comment: It seems like there's a deeper issue here. I can't see any documented reason why I shouldn't be able to have multiple `cursor.next()` calls "pending" at once - and it does seem to work fine with your `finally` block. I just have no idea why...

Comment: @JoeRocc The "documented reason" is what I already explained. The **"Server"** cannot instantiate the same cursor reference to the same local handle **multiple times**. Read the answer "carefully" as it's all explained there ( without going into multiple pages ). What you are expecting is inherently wrong, which is also explained and commented on as well as explained "why".

Comment: "This is why you do not want to call .next() in a loop without .hasNext() wrapping that call. Otherwise multiple calls actually try to instantiate the cursor on the server." I explained that it still fails with `.hasNext` in the `go` function and I explained that the `finally` block seems to have something to do with the error (if you take it away, you get the error). I also explained that your code examples seem to have race conditions. If you could reply to those queries, that would be great.

Comment: Oh, hang on, I may get what you're saying here. You're basically saying that  when you call `cursor.next` the driver doesn't first check to see if there's an instantiation of that cursor pending? If so, that seems like bizarre behaviour.

Comment: @JoeRocc Dude. Second listing. Please spend a couple of hours reading and re-reading and looking up the reference sources around it. You are missing all the core parts already mentioned. Also please don't fall into a a trap of mistaking your own misunderstanding for bugs in software. There is a much wider userbase out there than yourself. So you need to understand why what I am doing is "correct" and what you are asking is not what you do. Your comment just made indicates you are beginning to grasp it. But it's probably going to take a bit more to sink in. You don't call `.next()` in parallel.

Comment: I've come across seemingly elementary [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700933/993683) in this driver before, so I don't think it's too presumptuous of me to think this is unexpected behaviour. Your second code-snippet doesn't solve my problem as explained in the first sentence of my question. If your answer is "the driver can't handle multiple simultaneous pending `cursor.next()` calls" then a single-sentence answer with a simple link to documentation explaining that would do fine. Sorry if I've frustrated you.

Comment: @JoeRocc Dude. Again please walk away and take the time to let this sink in. This is not a bug. This is how things are supposed to work and your expectation is what is incorrect. Maybe it's your demonstration case that does not really explain what you think you want to implement. But If I have to point out basic errors in understanding which functions are async and which are not then maybe you should be paying attention to what you are being told rather than what you think. All your comments are basically repeating "but I think this" despite being told to the contrary.

Comment: Mate, to be fair, your explanations have been a bit all over the place. You yourself said that my initial solution was correct except for `await`ing the `.find()` (which wasn't the cause of the bug), and then gave me a solution with a pretty obvious race condition. So I'd appreciate it if you weren't quite so rude - given that you don't quite seem to know what's going on yourself. Sorry again that I've frustrated you, I think we can leave this one here.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Edit: While this answer *does* work, [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780632/calling-cursor-next-multiple-times-concurrently-crashes-the-driver/46782269#46782269) is a much better solution to this problem. Leaving this answer for prosperity.</strike> **Edit 2:** Other answer was wrong :(

---

Okay, so I sorted out the `waitForCursor` function so it doesn't have the race condition thing, and thus seems to work fine:

```
let cursorBusy = false;
async function go() {
  await waitForCursorLock();
  let doc = await cursor.next();
  cursorBusy = false;
  console.log(doc.num);
}
function waitForCursorLock() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let si = setInterval(() => {
      if(!cursorBusy) {
        cursorBusy = true;
        resolve();
        clearInterval(si);
      }
    }, 50);
  });
}
```

That's pretty gross though, so I probably won't accept this answer. If you can come up with a better one, please post it!

Comment: No, just...no. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Edit: This doesn't work. (see comments)

Inspired by @NeilLunn's explanations, all we need to do to fix the original code is add an `await cursor.hasNext();` right after we create the cursor:

```
(async function() {

  // create a collection for testing:
  let db = await require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tester-db-478364');

  await db.collection("test").drop();

  await db.collection('test').insertMany(
    Array(1000).fill(1).map((e,num) => ({ num, foo: 'bar' }))
  );

  let cursor = db.collection("test").find({});
  await cursor.hasNext(); // <-- add this line to "pre-instantiate" cursor

  async function go() {
    let doc = await cursor.next();
    console.log(doc.num);
  }

  // start 100 simulataneous requests to `cursor.next()`
  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    go();
  }

})();
```

This is because the cursor isn't actually instantiated until it's *used* (e.g. with `.next`, `.hasNext`, etc.), and the driver seems to have a quirk where it doesn't check to see if the cursor is already being instantiated, so it ends up sending many requests to the server which likely causes the error (too many connections, perhaps). We solve this by calling a "useless" `await cursor.hasNext()` up-front so the cursor in instantiated, then we can do as many "concurrent" calls to `cursor.next` as we like without errors.

So despite the other discussions in this thread, it seems that **it's possible to call `cursor.next` as fast as you like (in parallel)** without getting errors or unusual behaviour, so long as you've first triggered (and waited for) the cursor instantiation.

Ideally the driver would simply check to see if a cursor initialisation is already taking place, and just wait for that to finish, but perhaps there's some strange technical reason why that can't/won't be done.

Comment: If you change your `for` loop to 1000, this fails. The issue has to do with the cursor fetching the next batch of docs rather than one-time "cursor initialization". So it's not just the first batch that would be affected and you need to move the `await cursor.hasNext();` call inside of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I was just debugging that exact problem. So when a batch is used up, if we don't `await` a single call to the cursor (`hasNext`, say), then the driver spams a bunch of requests for new batches rather than realising that it has already sent a request? My architecture relies on events which trigger requests to the database (using same cursor so a different doc is returned each time). So it looks `.next` isn't designed with any sort of "potentially parallel" use case in mind. The gross "cursor lock" solution beats an architecture change though :/

Comment: There's just no benefit that I see to making multiple calls to `cursor.next()` without awaiting them.  If more docs are available in the current batch, the await resolves immediately; if not, you need to wait for the next batch to be fetched anyway. The other route to take would be to [stream](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#stream) the cursor results to your handlers. That event-based approach might be a better fit for your architecture.

Comment: I should have been much more clear about the architecture/motivation at the start of my original question (I've edited it to add motivation now). I will definitely look into other potential architectures using streams. Thanks a bunch for your help!